# Select a backtick-delimited block, rather than an inline string?

Tags: visual-mode

I'm editing some Javascript in which the following is common:

```js
var foo = `
  a bunch
  of text
  and stuff
`;
```

And I'd like to quickly be able to select the entire block between the backticks, like I would with the command `vib` if it were inside parens rather than backticks.

But it only seems to treat backticks as inline rather than block, and I'm not sure how to get around that.

Answer (score 2):

`ib` is referred to as a text object.  You can achieve *very* basic functionality using:

```
function! Ticks(inner)
    normal! gv
    call searchpos('`', 'bW')
    if a:inner | exe "normal! 1\<space>" | endif
    normal! o
    call searchpos('`', 'W')
    if a:inner | exe "normal! \<bs>" | endif
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> a` :<c-u>call Ticks(0)<cr>
vnoremap <silent> i` :<c-u>call Ticks(1)<cr>

onoremap <silent> a` :<c-u>normal va`<cr>
onoremap <silent> i` :<c-u>normal vi`<cr>
```

It is usually more robust to use a plugin designed for this.  There are many plugins implementing different text objects.  You may be interested specifically in:

- https://github.com/fvictorio/vim-textobj-backticks
- https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user (dependency of the above)
- https://github.com/thinca/vim-textobj-between

Comment: That's perfect, I had no idea there were text object plugins.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

#### Plugin `targets.vim` by Christian Wellenbrock (aka wellle)

This plugin provides following *four* text-objects:

1. `` i` `` - Select *inside backticks*:

   ```
   a ` bbbbbbbb ` e
      └── i` ──┘
   ```
2. `` a` `` - Select including backticks.

   ```
   a ` bbbbbbbb ` e
     └─── a` ───┘
   ```
3. `` I` `` - Like *inside backticks*, but exclude whitespace at
   both ends. Useful for changing contents while preserving spacing.

   ```
   a ` bbbbbbbb ` e
       └─ I` ─┘
   ```
4. `` A` `` - Select around a quote. Like a quote, but include whitespace in one
   direction. Prefers to select trailing whitespace, falls back to select
   leading whitespace.

   ```
   a ` bbbbbbbb ` e
     └─── A` ────┘
   ```

Please note, this plugin tries to improve the built-in text-objects. This can be a matter of taste.

You can find the documentation here:

- https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#quote-text-objects
- `:h targets-quote-text-objects`

**Update**
As already mentioned there are  many plugins. Not yet mentioned are:

- https://github.com/paradigm/TextObjectify
- https://github.com/kurkale6ka/vim-pairs

and a few plugins try to offer a *smart selection*

- https://github.com/gcmt/wildfire.vim
- https://github.com/gorkunov/smartpairs.vim

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @Mass I wanted to select the code blocks inside markdown files, so I came up with this, while inside

```bash
code blocks
```

```
function! InsideTicks()
    call searchpos('`', 'b')
    normal! jv
    call searchpos('`', 'W')
    normal! be
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>mc :<c-u>call InsideTicksTicks()<cr>
```

I did not find any other references, so I will let this too, just in case someone finds it useful.

Thank you